# Hebrew strings submitted to web server aren't received in Hebrew

Tags: android, hebrew

I submit a sign up form from my app to the web server:

```
EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
EditText nickname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nickname);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email.getText().toString()));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nickname", nickname.getText().toString()));

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

When I type the nickname in Hebrew, it is received in the server (php/apache) as a string in the same length as the nickname, but with characters which are "invisible", i.e. look like blank spaces. definitely not Hebrew. Any clue someone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that just doing `request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));` encodes your parameters in the DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET (see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html).

You should probably use the `UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<? extends NameValuePair> parameters, String encoding)` form. Froyo/Android 2.2 added support for displaying text in Hebrew and Arabic (among other languages), including the needed fonts, but I am still looking for Hebrew  encoding string...

Have you tried encoding as "UTF-8" or "UTF-16"?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. However I suspect the string *is* posted in utf8 since I run PHP's mb_detect_encoding on it on the server side and it returns 'UTF8'.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is on the web side. If you're sending it as UTF-8 but the web page doesn't have something like <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> then the website might be mis-interpreting the characters?

Comment: I tested it now with request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8)); and it worked like a charm! Thanks!